# assign each value of a column into a dynamically created global array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to store each value of a column from a text file into an dynamically allocated array, which needs to be globally declared for further usage in the program.

The input textfile contains the following:
34932\t13854\t13854\t2012-01-07\r
172098\t49418\t53269\t2012-01-07\r

I have written the following code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE *int_file1;
        int BUF = 1024;

        char first_col[BUF],sec_col[BUF],third_col[BUF],fourth_col[BUF];

        int index=0,i=0;

        char *array1=malloc(10*sizeof(char));

        int_file1=fopen("test.txt","r");

        if(int_file1 == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            while(fscanf(int_file1,"%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t[^\n]",first_col,sec_col,third_col,fourth_col) == 4)
            {
                             //printf("%s",first_col);
                 array1=realloc(array1,strlen(first_col)+1);
                 array1[index]=first_col;
                 index++;
            }
        }

        fclose(int_file1);  

        printf("%s",array1[1]);

        return 0;
    }
```

The commented printf line gives the entire values of the column, which proves that the file is correctly being read.

But on compiling this program I get both compiler warnings and finally segmentation fault.

Please suggest where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: It would help if you posted the compiler warnings, also, what line is it segfaulting on?

Comment: The compiler errors are:

Comment: program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:113: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
program.c:120: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

Comment: Fix those warnings and your problem will likely be fixed. If you can't make sense of them, paste them into google and read about what causes those warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the question was posted only after being unable to seek answers by googling!! Hope somebody nice can clear my understanding..

Comment: It looks like I'm all you've got.   Lets start the ball rolling with two questions: what are you trying to store in `array1`, and, what is the goal of this assignment `array1[index]=first_col;`?

Comment: Thanks for turning nicer!! I want "172098" as the output. I have written the same program without using realloc and the program ran fine (Can't post in this comment but if you want i can post it as well) But, I wanted to generalize my program for a file of unknown size and hence opted to use realloc.

Comment: So, the answers to your questions are: 1) I want to store the first col elements as a string in array1 and 2) Since "while" reads line by line so, I thought of saving each element of first col into array1[0], array1[1]... I had tried using strcpy to do the assignment as in my earlier code but it didn't work either; so checked few examples in the forum and came up with this assignment.

Comment: Since my earlier program worked with the same declaration types so I am puzzled if the problem is with declaration as stated in compiler errors or is there some problem with realloc in my code..

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a `char *` and a `char`, and what a "string" is. As first allocated, `array1` can store, at most, 10 `chars`. To store a `char *` at each index (array1[0]...) you'd need to have it be `char ** array1` and `malloc(10*sizeof(char *));` However, you then run into the problem that you need to create space to store the strings (since `first_col` is overwritten on each `while` iteration). You can use `strdup()` and do `array1[indx] = strdup(first_col);` `strdup()` does 2 things, it `malloc()s` memory, and it does a `strcpy()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Your suggestions have indeed solved my problem but I think I need to read more about pointers and so I am back to textbooks on pointers. Thanks for introducing the new function strdup.. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this if it could help
Instead of this

```
array1=realloc(array1,strlen(first_col)+1);
```

try doing this

```
temp = realloc(array1,strlen(first_col)+1);

array1=temp;
```

and

```
array1[index]=first_col;//You can't do this, You can do this if array1 is double pointer.
```